# How to use ffmpeg using C, for audio conversion

Tags: android, c, ffmpeg

We know ffmpeg to convert an mp3 to wav, as in the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i testlong.mp3 -f wav output.wav
```

However, I would like to know how to achieve the above command line function with C language.

> ps: I want to achieve in the  Android devices, convert audio formats, 
>   in addition to ffmpeg, I do not know what a good solution.

Thanks！

Answer (score 0):

One way is to compile the entire `ffmpeg.c` file into your application and then generate the command line within your application, then pass it on into ffmpeg's `main()` (that you will probably rename). The other way is to study the its source code, online tutorials, ... and write your own converter based on that.

Answer (score 0):

Compile ffmpeg for android
Below link has some way to perform that.

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Android

Now you can put all code of ffmpeg in JNI folder and use its methods in c to Java methods and use it in java activity.

Other method is just cross compile ffmpeg and install it in android.

then using `system()` call in java use that `ffmpeg -i testlong.mp3 -f wav output.wav`